# Навигация вида "хлебные крошки"

Tags: php

Стала задача написать на php хлебные крошки (навигационную цепочку), раньше ни разу этого не делал, однако хочу сам понять, как это можно реализовать. В Яндексе и в Гугле в основном упоминается решения для Wordpress, которое не подходит для моей самописной CMS. Пожалуйста, подскажите, алгоритм реализации хлебных крошек на PHP, буду также рад другим незначительным подсказкам по данному вопросу. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: > хочу *сам* понять
so...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В сессии хранить массив id, пар "ссылка-название" или уникальных имён типа `Array('root','Category','Subcategory');` - как именно, зависит от вашей CMS.

Перед переходом по очередной ссылке добавлять туда или убирать хвост.

И выводить строку, перебирая этот массив от начала к концу. Что-то типа:

```
$Breadcrumbs = Array( 15=>'Начало', 27=>'Продукты', 36=>'Колбаса');
// на самом деле будет типа $Breadcrumbs = $app->getCrumbs();
$after = false; // для вывода > перед очередной ссылку "крошек"
foreach( $Breadcrumbs AS $id=>$title) {
    if( $after) { echo ' &gt; ' } else $after = true; 
    printf( '<a href="index.php?page=%d">%s</a> ', $id, $title);
}
```